# Unable to hear "今" in "今の文章の和訳をお願いします"

Tags: listening

At [2m39s of the first episode of Death Note](https://animelon.com/video/5762abf7fc68e08dcd850d84), the sentence

> **今**の文章の和訳をお願いします

is uttered. The first word is given the reading "いま" by the subtitles, but I don't hear that being spoken? Instead I think I hear something like "こりま" (though I'm totally new to Japanese listening so don't necessarily trust myself). I'm curious if other people hear this too, or if the reading provided by animelon is somehow incorrect.

Comment: The subtitle is correct, and the teacher is clearly saying いまの (*imano*), not こりま (*korima*). Is your native language American English?

Comment: Is it just the fact that there are some people whispering at the same time? It's hard to make out what they're saying, but maybe that sound interfered with your ability to hear 今.

Comment: @naruto: American English is my native language, yes. :]

Comment: @George Hmm...I can hear nothing that sounds like こりま. Does the "の文章の和訳をお願いします" part sound okay to you? 今 is the only strange part?

Comment: @naruto Yes everything else sounds as translated, but for some reason that first word I hear what sounds like a clear k-sound as the very first mora.  I think I'm just inexperienced listening to Japanese :)

Comment: I do hear a /k/ sound. It could be due to a recording error or something?

Comment: 背景の生徒のしゃべり声が混じって聞こえてるのでは。男子生徒の「おい、これ見ろよ」の「こ」の直後に教師の「いまの...」のセリフが重なって。